# Modprobe floppy not found for Rocky Linux 8.4

Tags: linux, packer

On installing Rocky Linux 8.4 with Packer and vCenter 6.5., there is an error message that modprobe cannot find floppy module in the kernel folder.

Does this mean this distribution has no support for floppy disk?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually it means that
[Linux finally dropping floppy drive support](https://techreport.com/news/3464145/linux-dropping-floppy-drive-support/).

This was in 2019
[announced by Linus Torvalds](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/47d6a7607443ea43dbc4d0f371bf773540a8f8f4):

> Actual working physical floppy hardware is getting hard to find, and
> while Willy was able to test this, I think the driver can be considered
> pretty much dead from an actual hardware standpoint.  The hardware that
> is still sold seems to be mainly USB-based, which doesn't use this
> legacy driver at all.

Comment: bad enough the packer plugin does not support USB file provisioning yet as it seems.